# Apply cache manifest only in production mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, offline-caching

I've added a "cache.manifest" in my application (this works perfectly) and since then, it's very hard to debug since I must always clear the cache or modify the cache.manifest version.

I tryied to load the manifest with "HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled" condition:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  @if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
  {
    <html>
  }
  else
  {
    <html manifest="/cache.manifest">
  }
```

This doesn't works and Visual Studio gives me 3 errors:

- The block is missing a closing } character
- **html** element is not closed
- Can't have more than 1 **html** element.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer from "sav931", I finally found the solution:

```
<html @(HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled ? "" :  "manifest=cache.manifest" )>
```

No need to add an app setting key in the web.config, since there's already a function for that. (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)

Also, I removed the manfest attribut completely when developping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add key in the web.config like:

```
<add key="devMode" value="true"/>
```

and now add this in your View:

```
<head @(Convert.ToBoolean(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["devMode"]) ? "manifest=/cache.manifest" : "manifest=devMode.manifest")>
```

by adding a manifest file name that not exist it will disable the cache...

Comment: Thanks ! This solution is working and I adapted it by using HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled to make it cleaner.